# combine sort by high and low into one function react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 working functions that will allow me to sort by price high/low `handleSortCheapest` and `handleSortExpensive`, what I would like to do is combine these into 1 function `handleSort` that will be called via an onCLick function and the parameter passed to it will determine whether it sorts high or low e.g `onClick={()=> this.handleSort(high)}`

I have attempted to write a function that will do this but it doesn't work so how can I create a function that will do this?

```
handleSortCheapest = () => {
          this.setState({
            sortValue: this.state.data.sort((a,b) => (parseFloat(a.price) - parseFloat(b.price)))
          })
        }

    // Sort price high to low
    handleSortExpensive = () => {
      this.setState({
        sortValue: this.state.data.sort((a,b) => (parseFloat(b.price) - parseFloat(a.price))),
      })
    }


    handleSort = value => {
      const low = this.state.data.sort((a,b) => (parseFloat(a.price) - parseFloat(b.price)))
      const high = this.state.data.sort((a,b) => (parseFloat(b.price) - parseFloat(a.price)))
      this.setState({
        sortValue: value
      })
    }

    onClick={()=> this.handleSort(high)}
    onClick={()=>this.handleSort(low)}
```

Comment: Theoretically, you could use `Array.reverse` after you added the data sorted by either high or low (as you are just reversing the order). Personally, I would leave the data unsorted in the state, and only sort / filter the data when actually showing it. As really, no state is changing, just re-ordering is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing at what "doesn't work" means and I am assuming that the `onClick` settings are part of JSX content such as within `render()`. I also assume that `data` is an array which is part of the object state.

One problem is that `high` and `low` are not valid outside the scope of the anonymous function assigned to `handleSort` arrow-function. Even if this did work, I'd probably just use a `boolean` parameter to `handleSort()` rather than passing functions around.

```
handleSort = ascending => {
   this.setState( {
       sortValue: ascending 
                  ? this.state.data.sort((a,b) => (parseFloat(a.price) - parseFloat(b.price)))
                  : this.state.data.sort((a,b) => (parseFloat(b.price) - parseFloat(a.price)))
   } )
}
```

Then invoke it within JSX render code:

```
render(
   … onClick={() => this.handleSort(true)} … // ascending, low to high
   … onClick={() => this.handleSort(false)} …     // descending, high to low
)
```